# Lungopò senza accento

Tags: accents

Su [questa notizia](https://torino.repubblica.it/cronaca/2019/04/05/news/torino_il_killer_dei_murazzi_libero_per_un_errore_giudiziario_arrivan_gli_ispettori_del_ministero-223324889/?ref=RHPPLF-BH-I0-C8-P1-S1.8-T1) leggo la parola [lungopò](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lungopo) priva dell'accento. Questa scrittura è comune/accettabile? Non vengo da una città sulle sponde di questo fiume, quindi mi è sembrato abbastanza strano leggerla. Il vocabolario Treccani non riporta questa variante, e per analogia con tre / ventitré mi sarei aspettato di leggerla con l'accento.

D'altra parte, la notizia viene dal sito di uno dei maggiori quotidiani, quindi mi aspetterei un italiano ben rivisto (anche se gli errori di battitura sono sempre in agguato).

Answer (score 4):

Non c'è dubbio che l'accento ci va. Nel glossario finale dell'*Italiano* di Serianni si legge:

> La regola per la quale l'accento tonico va segnato su tutte le parole polisillabiche (cioè di due o più sillabe) accentate sull'ultima non ammette eccezioni: quindi *ventitré*, *trentatré* ecc. e anche *nontiscordardimé* e *viceré*.

All'interno del testo c'è anche un accenno rapido alle norme UNI relative a questo e alla sillabazione.

<sub>Non prenderei *la Repubblica* esattamente come maestra di precisione ed esattezza...</sub>

Comment: [Non ammette eccezioni?](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/garni)

Comment: O, per un esempio più comune, [menu](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/menu/).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Quelli sono prestiti dal francese, scritti con la grafia francese (e riportati infatti in corsivo nel dizionario). 
Per [“menù” esiste anche la grafia italiana, con l'accento scritto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/menu_res-0e9f9495-0026-11de-9d89-0016357eee51).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Controprova: se scrivi [_mélange_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/melange) alla francese (e in corsivo come gli altri prestiti non assimilati), mantieni l'accento dell'ortografia francese nonostante non indichi un accento tonico italiano.

Comment: Stai cercando di spiegarmi il motivo per cui esistono queste eccezioni, ma non è questo il punto. Il mio punto è che *esistono* eccezioni, e che Serianni forse dovrebbe essere più cauto quando fa affermazioni categoriche.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Non sono eccezioni, perché non sono parole italiane (come conferma il fatto che si scrivono in corsivo). Se usi una parola straniera in una frase italiana, non diventa un'eccezione all'ortografia italiana. Il Treccani registra anche [_Übermensch_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ubermensch), ma non per questo l'_Umlaut_ è un segno diacritico della lingua italiana.